# Error while acknowledging stomp message

Tags: spring, websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

We are using spring stomp over websockets, backed by ActiveMQ 5.11.1.
When the client ACKs a message, I get this exception:

```
"<<< ERROR
```

content-type:text/plain
message:Unexpected ACK received for message-id [ID\cjanus-61128-1430365808166-2\c1\c-1\c1\c1]
content-length:722

org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolException: Unexpected ACK received for message-id [ID:janus-61128-1430365808166-2:1:-1:1:1]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.onStompAck(ProtocolConverter.java:462)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolConverter.onStompCommand(ProtocolConverter.java:247)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompTransportFilter.onCommand(StompTransportFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Here is the client code:

```
  var sub_id = stompClient.subscribe('/user/guest/msg', function(greeting){              
                x = JSON.parse(greeting.body);
                var message_id = greeting.headers['message-id']
                stompClient.ack(message_id, sub_id);
             }, {ack: 'client'});
```

I tried to set the ack to client-individual and that didn't help.
Can some one tell me what I am missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which STOMP version (1.0, 1.1 or 1.2) does the connection use? STOMP 1.2 has a [breaking change](http://stomp.github.io//stomp-specification-1.2.html#ACK):

> The ACK frame MUST include an id header matching the ack header of the
>   MESSAGE being acknowledged.

I suggest to capture the STOMP traffic with a packet sniffer or a debugger and compare the headers with the specification.

Comment: Thanks! I used STOMP 1.1 and had to send in subscription Id and message Id like this: stompClient.ack(message_id, subscription_id); I had to dig into the source AMQ src code to find this.